# /tp in an area problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I recently wanted to make a force field so that some players can't access the area above this force field, and for this, I've made this command (on picture) and here is what it says: 
[image]

I don't understand what is wrong in my command; unless it is the system ?

[image]

Comment: I see you are playing 1.9. Please remove the redstone clock and set the command block to "repeat" instead. This way, you prevent redstone lag, which can cause problems if you have a lot of clocks like this.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it is real that I hate redstone lags :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your command is `/tp @a [x=-3,y=1,z=0,dx=-9,dy=7,dz=0] ~ ~ ~-1`

I see one error with this: you need to have the `@a` and `[` touching.

Fixed command:

`/tp @a[x=-12,y=1,z=0,dx=9,dy=7,dz=0] ~ ~ ~-1`

Comment: Your second point is incorrect; delta parameters may be negative and 0.

Comment: How do they work with 0?

Comment: It targets players at the same blockspace as the specified coordinates. Otherwise it's the number of blocks in the specified direction from the coordinates (such as a value of `dx=1` encompassing 2 blocks; the origin and 1 block in the X direction).

Comment: It going ever worse; the little line that appear after the command is run don't even do now (I'm not saying for the comment but for the answer)

Comment: If I understand your complaint correctly, then I, too, encounter this problem. It seems to happen only on command blocks set to 'always active'. try setting it to impulse on a clock, and see if that works.

Comment: @Kimatuy Does changing to a normal redstone clock help?

Comment: Nope, it still don't work, plus the command block was in"need redstone" mode when I made it run with the clock